# C# percentile rank algorithm

Tags: c#, math, statistics

I'm trying to reverse engineer a calculation that was done on an old program but can't quite get it. I need a count of how many values are in the top 27%, middle 46%, and bottom 27%.

I have the following data sets with eleven values in each and what the program yields in regards to the percentages and the number of values that fall into those percentiles.

```
Upper 27%: 4, Middle 46%: 4, Lower 27%: 3
values: 8,9,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,13

Upper 27%: 5, Middle 46%: 4, Lower 27%: 2
values: 2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5

Upper 27%: 2, Middle 46%: 8, Lower 27%: 1
values: 2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5

Upper 27%: 2, Middle 46%: 6, Lower 27%: 3
values: 13,17,17,18,19,19,19,21,21,23,24
```

I have found formulas such as (n * p) where n is the number of values and p is the percentile but it doesn't seem to work across all of these data sets to give the same results. I'm a little lost and haven't found anything that produces the results here.

I have tested code that I have found on the internet but none have worked on the different data sets.

Code sample that I tried:

```
    internal static double percentile(double[] sortedData, double p)
    {
        if (p >= 100.0d) return sortedData[sortedData.Length - 1];

        double position = (double)(sortedData.Length + 1) * p / 100.0;
        double leftNumber = 0.0d, rightNumber = 0.0d;

        double n = p / 100.0d * (sortedData.Length - 1) + 1.0d;

        if (position >= 1)
        {
            leftNumber = sortedData[(int)System.Math.Floor(n) - 1];
            rightNumber = sortedData[(int)System.Math.Floor(n)];
        }
        else
        {
            leftNumber = sortedData[0]; // first data
            rightNumber = sortedData[1]; // first data
        }

        if (leftNumber == rightNumber)
            return leftNumber;
        else
        {
            double part = n - System.Math.Floor(n);
            return leftNumber + part * (rightNumber - leftNumber);
        }
    }
```

Is there a formula or a name for what I am trying to do? Am I on the right track with percentile ranks?

Comment: Your code that implements your reversed engineered attempt at the algorithm looks fine ...

Comment: Please provide us with a clear question and show us what you've tried (post some code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right path. This is indeed the percentile rank formula. My initial thought was to get the value at the 27th percentile (*which looking at your code it looks like you started down this path as well*) and figure out how many values were greater than or less than; but the values you provided don't support these numbers very well.

Therefore the approach I took was to calculate the percentile rank of each number and put it into a count if they matched the percentile you have above. This seems to be the approach they took.

Formula [(check out this website for more info)](https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/percentile-rank.php):

`PR% = L + ( 0.5 x S ) / N
Where,
L = Number of below rank,
S = Number of same rank,
N = Total numbers.`

Code:

```
var lower = 0;
var middle = 0;
var upper = 0;

// var values = new int[] { 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13 };
// var values = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
// var values = new int[] { 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
var values = new int[] { 13, 17, 17, 18, 19, 19, 19, 21, 21, 23, 24 };

var n = values.Length;

foreach(var i in values)
{
    var pr = ((values.Count(v => v < i) + (.5 * values.Count(v => v == i))) / n);
    if (pr < .27)
        lower += 1;
    else if (pr > .73)
        upper += 1;
    else
        middle += 1;
}

Console.WriteLine("Upper: " + upper);
Console.WriteLine("Middle: " + middle);
Console.WriteLine("Lower: " + lower);
```

Comment: You're awesome. I didn't get further than your initial approach. That was what I was trying.

Comment: Yeah, I was scratching my head at first, but anytime rounding is involved there is room for statistical error.